# Не работает аннотация типов. IDE не выводит подсказки. Что не так?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import RLock


def main(locker: RLock) -> None:
    locker.acquire() # Не выводит подсказки, попробуйте набрать у себя


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = RLock()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=main, args=(lock,)).start()
```

При обращении внутри функции к аргументу locker, ide не выводит методы. Проверял на pycharm, vscode

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если передать RLock явно, то выводит подсказки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так ведь не должно быть, почему возникает такая аномалия? Я ведь указал тайпхинт, подсказки должны быть в любом случае

Comment: `from multiprocessing.synchronize import RLock`

Answer (score 1):

видимо потому что сам класс RLock находится в multiprocessing.synchronize, если указать от туда то все выводится

```
import multiprocessing.synchronize
import multiprocessing

def main(locker: multiprocessing.synchronize.RLock) -> None:
    locker.acquire()  # выводит подсказки

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main(multiprocessing.RLock())
    pass
```